# Rotating captions with adjustbox does not work when floatrow package is loaded

Tags: floats, captions, rotating, floatrow, adjustbox

I tried to rotate a figure and its caption using the `adjustbox` package.
This works fine, until I load the `floatrow` package too, then the caption isn't rotated.

See my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{floatrow} 

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\caption{%
      Here is a caption of the figure which is so long that 
      it has to be wrapped over multiple lines, but should 
      not exceed the width (height after the rotation) of the image.
      }\end{minipage}},rotate=90,center}
      \includegraphics[scale=.6]{example-image}%
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I checked both package documentations for references to one another, but there doesn't seem to be anything.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `floatrow` redefines the  internal code of the `\caption` command and hooks into the `figure` environment code. It then *stores* the caption text first internally and reinserts it in the configured position, either top or bottom of the figure content. The normal behavior without that package is that the caption is placed immediately.

As it is not placed where the code is written -- inside the `adjustbox` environment -- then it can't be rotated by that environment! Instead it is reinserted later as mentioned above.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to force `floatrow` here to just place the caption as normal, as it does not look to be designed for that. Then, `adjustbox` here can't do anything about it. I would recommend to live with it or to try to change to another float package which gives you the features you want but lets the captions as they are.

However, a complete solution which hacks the internal code of `float` again and places the rotating code after the `floatrow` code would be possible I guess, but a little overkill.